# PHP and Xpath, filtering results based on greatgrandchildren

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Consider the following test.xml

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <child1>Value1</child1>
        <child2>value11</child2>
        <child3>
             <grandchild>
                  <greatgrandchild>value1111</greatgrandchild>
             </grandchild>
        </child3>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <child1>value2</child1>
         <child3>
             <grandchild>
                  <greatgrandchild>value2222</greatgrandchild>
             </grandchild>
        </child3>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <child1>value3</child1>
        <child2>value33</child2>
        <child3>
             <grandchild>
                  <greatgrandchild>value3333</greatgrandchild>
             </grandchild>
        </child3>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <child1>value4</child1>
        <child2>value44</child2>
        <child3>
             <grandchild>
                  <greatgrandchild>value4444</greatgrandchild>
             </grandchild>
        </child3>
        </parent>
</root>
```

When I use the following for xpath '/root/parent', I can easily get the values of ID, child1, and child2.

However I do not get the values of the greatgrandchild of grandchild.

What can I do to get these values.

```
$query = '/root/parent'
$xQuery = $xml->xpath($query);
foreach($xQuery as $results){
    echo $results->ID;
    echo $results->child1;
    echo $results->child2;
    echo $results->greatgrandchild;
}
```

I would like to filter the result based on the value of greatgrandchild. I can successfully filter the results of ID and child1 and child2. I want to be getting a parent and all of its children and grandchildren and greatgrandchild based on the value of greatgrandchild.

Is this possible using xpath?

I have edited the wording of the question and used the proper test.xml as I had errors in it the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code,

- `grandchild` node is ambiguous and malformed. The closing tag of `grandchild2` is `grandchild` which is wrong.

  ```
  This is wrong------------+
                           |  
                           v
  <grandchild2>value3333</grandchild>
  ```
- `$results->grandchild` does not exists, rather use `$results->child3->grandchild`. Here Xpath returns all the `parent` nodes under `root` node as `SimpleXMLElement`

To find all the `parent` element whose `child1=value3` and `grandchild1=value333` use this query.

```
/root/parent[child1 = "value3" and child3/grandchild = "value333"]
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I had made this xml just to make it easier to understand what I was trying to achieve. This is not the same xml file I am using. I have edited the error in the xml format. I am still not able to get the value of the grandchildren.

Comment: See the second bullet point of my answer. Thats what you need.

Comment: Ok perfect!. One more question though. How can i test the value of greatgrandchild and still be able to use the same for loop. For example the following xpath does not work. /root/parent[greatgrandchild=value333]. I know this does not work and that I would have to put something more on the line of /root/parent/child3/grandchild[greatgrandchild=value333]. However I also want to test the value of child 2. If it were SQL the statement would be Select parent from root where greatgrandchild = value333 and child1 = value3. Is it possible to merge two xpath filters like so?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I hadn't accepted. Better late then never.